# Yii2 pagination with only previous and next button hide page numbers

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I want yii2 pagination to display only Previous and Next buttons excuding page number's links.

I have searched but not found proper solution.

My pagination widget in view :

```
<?php echo LinkPager::widget([

    'pagination' => $pagination,

    'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',

    'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',

    ]); 

?>
```

I just want Previous and Next buttons in pagination and hide page numbers link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `maxButtonCount` to **0**.

```
<?= LinkPager::widget([
   'pagination' => $pagination,
   'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
   'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
   'maxButtonCount' => 0,
]); ?>
```